# Cross account dataframe write to s3 bucket ownership

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, boto3

I am using a jupyter notebook inside of EMR. Have attempted many ways to set the spark context for this, but it is not working.

```
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.canned.acl", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.canned.acl", "bucket-owner-full-control")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.acl.default', 'bucket-owner-full-control')
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.acl.default","BucketOwnerFullControl")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.acl.default", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.acl.default", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3.canned.acl", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3.acl.default", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.acl.default", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.acl.default.override", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.acl.default.override", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.acl.default", "bucket-owner-full-control")
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.acl.default.override", "bucket-owner-full-control")
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.acl.default.override", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.acl.default", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3.canned.acl", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3.acl.default", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.acl.default", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.acl.default", "bucket-owner-full-control")
```

I am using pyspark and have attempted combinations of the above to do this

```
df.limit(1).write \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("fs.s3a.acl.default", "BucketOwnerFullControl") \
    .parquet("s3://mybucket/test.parquet")
```

The write does go through from account a to account b. The problem is that every time I write variation of the above dataframe write, it fails to correctly assign ownership to account b (the one written to).

Even copying from account b to itself results in a permission denied because of the way it is written.

So my question is. What is the proper way to write from one aws account to another (that you have permission to do so)?